# Calendar View without horizontal scroll

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, calendarview

I´m trying to use a Calendar View (Android Studio Widget) with horizontal scrolling. In design view the calendar appears fixed with arrows to scroll, that is what i want, but when i run the app, the calendar appears with vertical scrolling showing some months. I want to show only the present month and scroll with arrows horizontally.

Xml code:

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.328" />
```

App view:

[image]

Design view (what I want):

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEPx6.png):

Comment: use material calender view

Comment: https://androidexample365.com/a-simple-and-customizable-calendar-widget-for-android-based-on-material-design/